# Is my computer compatible with this graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, compatibility, pci

I'm not too knowledgable with hardware and want to buy a new cheap graphics card...

its PCI express 2.1

the link: 
http://komplett.ie/Komplett/product/ZKB_01COM/10_GRPCARD/04_PCI-E/productdetails/20029063/ASUS_EAH5450_SILENT_DI_512MD2(LP)_Graphics/90_C1CP2A_J0UANABZ/default.aspx

My PC:
http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dim9150/en/sm/specs.htm

i have a pentium 4 GPU. i currently have 1 gig of ram and plan to upgrade to 3... what do you think

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install this card. But your port is only 2.0, so you are not gonna use all the capabilities of the card. But it's a good card, I recommend it to you, even no getting the whole power.